# setInterval for variable to be false

Tags: javascript, setinterval

So I basically got a variable that is set to true, and what I want to achieve is so the variable turns to false after 2 seconds. How can I do this with the use of setInterval  ?

Comment: Do you have any code you wrote so far?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `setTimeout` instead. It will execute the anonymous function once.

```
var yourVar = true;
setTimeout(function(){ yourVar = false; }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to trigger some event or call some functions after 2 seconds, then:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
   function1();
   function2();
}, 2000);
// this will call functions after 2 seconds, when setTimeout will get called
```

And, if you want to call some functions after some particular event (condition) using `setInterval` then you have to use `clearInterval` to break the loop:

```js
var setint = setInterval(function(){
   if (check condition here) {
      function1();
      function2(); // .... so on
      clearInterval(setint); // break the setInterval loop
   }        
}, 100);
```

Comment: Please do not use the "runnable snippets" feature when your snippets are not runnable. Check your spelling before you hit "submit".

Comment: Thanks Lightness, for your suggestions and rectification

Comment: @Dinesh Gopal Chand   The problem is, I might be doing using it wrong. What I'm trying to accomplish is when visible is set to false, the circle's visibility is hidden and when its set to true it is visibile.

`function redActive(){
  var visible = true;
  setInterval(function (){
      visible = false;
      console.log(visible);
    },1000);
  return visible;
}
switch(redActive()){
  case visible = false:
    redCircle.style.visibility="hidden";
    break;
  case visible = true:
    redCircle.style.visibility="visible";
    break;
}`

Comment: @TudorApostol , I got your issue and when I went through you code I found mirror mistake. Try using setInterval on switch case i.e put your conditional block in the loop, no need to use setInterval in the redActive function. here is a simple demo. https://jsfiddle.net/googleCode/k4r3kj8j/ 


I believe this would help you.